# R Shiny CSS: Enable scrolling in the x and y direction in an application with several absolute panels

Tags: css, r, shiny, scroll, panel

I have an R Shiny application with several absolute panels.

The full application looks like this:

[image]

I would like users to be able to scroll in the x and y direction in instances when their browser window is too small to view all the panels at once.

Here is the code to render the application:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(leaflet)

ui <- shiny::navbarPage(

  # Enable use of shinyjs tools
  htmltools::div(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs()
  ),

  # Navbar Identification
  id = "nav",

  # Navbar position
  position = "static-top",

  # Test Tab
  shiny::tabPanel(title = "Test",
                  value = "test-tab",
              
              #-----PANEL 1-----
              
              shinyjs::inlineCSS("#u-panel-1.ap { padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 0px; background-color: #cccccc; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px; }"),
              
              shiny::absolutePanel(id = "u-panel-1",
                                   class = "ap",
                                   fixed = TRUE,
                                   draggable = FALSE,
                                   top = 180,
                                   left = 55,
                                   right = "auto",
                                   bottom = "auto",
                                   width = 200),
              
              #-----PANEL 2-----
              
              shinyjs::inlineCSS("#u-panel-2.ap { padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 0px; background-color: #cccccc; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px; }"),
              
              shiny::absolutePanel(id = "u-panel-2",
                                   class = "ap",
                                   fixed = TRUE,
                                   draggable = FALSE,
                                   top = 272,
                                   left = 55,
                                   right = "auto",
                                   bottom = "auto",
                                   width = 200),
              
              #-----PANEL 3-----
              
              shinyjs::inlineCSS("#u-panel-3.ap { padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 0px; background-color: #cccccc; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px; }"),
              
              shiny::absolutePanel(id = "u-panel-3",
                                   class = "ap",
                                   fixed = TRUE,
                                   draggable = FALSE,
                                   top = 180,
                                   left = 263,
                                   right = "auto",
                                   bottom = "auto",
                                   width = 429,
                                   height = 178),
              
              #-----PANEL 4-----
              
              shinyjs::inlineCSS("#u-panel-4.ap { padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 30px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px; background-color: #cccccc; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px; }"),
              
              shiny::absolutePanel(id = "u-panel-4",
                                   class = "ap",
                                   fixed = TRUE,
                                   draggable = FALSE,
                                   top = 180,
                                   left = 700,
                                   right = "auto",
                                   bottom = "auto",
                                   width = 429,
                                   height = 178),
              
              #-----PANEL 5-----
              
              shinyjs::inlineCSS("#u-panel-5.ap { padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 30px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px; background-color: #cccccc; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px; }"),
              
              shiny::absolutePanel(id = "u-panel-5",
                                   class = "ap",
                                   fixed = TRUE,
                                   draggable = FALSE,
                                   top = 366,
                                   left = 55,
                                   right = "auto",
                                   bottom = "auto",
                                   width = 1074,
                                   height = 220),
              
              #-----PANEL 6-----
              
              shinyjs::inlineCSS("#u-panel-6.ap { padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 0px; background-color: #8ebfdb; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px; }"),
              
              shiny::absolutePanel(id = "u-panel-6",
                                   class = "ap",
                                   fixed = TRUE,
                                   draggable = FALSE,
                                   top = 594,
                                   bottom = "auto",
                                   left = 55,
                                   right = "auto",
                                   height = 177,
                                   width = 425),
              
              #-----PANEL 7-----
              
              shinyjs::inlineCSS("#u-panel-7.ap { padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 0px; background-color: #f4ac90; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px; }"),
              
              shiny::absolutePanel(id = "u-panel-7",
                                   class = "ap",
                                   fixed = TRUE,
                                   draggable = FALSE,
                                   top = 594,
                                   left = 489,
                                   right = "auto",
                                   bottom = "auto",
                                   height = 177,
                                   width = 640),
              
              #-----MAP PANEL-----
              
              shiny::absolutePanel(id = "u-map-panel",
                                   class = "ap",
                                   fixed = TRUE,
                                   draggable = FALSE,
                                   top = 60,
                                   left = 1138,
                                   right = "auto",
                                   bottom = "auto",
                                   height = 526,
                                   width = 552,
                                   
                                   #-----RENDER MAP-----
                                   
                                   shinyjs::inlineCSS("#my-map { border-style: solid; border-color: black; margin: 0px; border-width: 1px; }"),
                                   
                                   leaflet::leafletOutput("my-map", width="100%", height="100%")
                                   
              )
              
  ) # ** End test tab ** #

) # ** End UI function ** #


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #-----BASE MAP UI OUTPUT-----

  output$`my-map` <- leaflet::renderLeaflet({
    # Establish interactive map
    interactiveMap <- leaflet::leaflet(options=leaflet::leafletOptions(minZoom = 4, zoomControl = TRUE, dragging = TRUE)) %>%
      leaflet::addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") 
    # Return result
    return(interactiveMap)
  })

} # ** End server function ** #


shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have searched through several forums and tried to implement CSS to solve this issue, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is a better way to do that, but if you define the `tabPanel` to have a fixed width and height (corresponding to the sum of all panels) and set each panel with `style = "position: absolute;"` you can scroll when the browser window is too small. Also you need to have a `navbar` with a fixed width.

[Here is the app running on shinyapps.io](https://geovany.shinyapps.io/absolute_panel/)

```R
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(leaflet)

ui <- shiny::navbarPage(

  # Enable use of shinyjs tools
  htmltools::div(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs()
  ),

  # Navbar Identification
  id = "nav",

  # Navbar position
  position = "static-top",
  
  # Test Tab
  shiny::tabPanel(title = "Test", style = "width: 1690px;height: 720px;",
                  value = "test-tab",
              #-----PANEL 1-----
              shinyjs::inlineCSS(".navbar {width: 1690px;}"),
              shinyjs::inlineCSS("#u-panel-1.ap { padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 0px; background-color: #cccccc; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px;}"),
              
              shiny::absolutePanel(id = "u-panel-1", style = "position: absolute;",
                                   class = "ap",
                                   fixed = TRUE,
                                   draggable = FALSE,
                                   top = 180,
                                   left = 55,
                                   right = "auto",
                                   bottom = "auto",
                                   width = 200),
              
              #-----PANEL 2-----
              
              shinyjs::inlineCSS("#u-panel-2.ap { padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 0px; background-color: #cccccc; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px;}"),
              
              shiny::absolutePanel(id = "u-panel-2", style = "position: absolute;",
                                   class = "ap",
                                   fixed = TRUE,
                                   draggable = FALSE,
                                   top = 272,
                                   left = 55,
                                   right = "auto",
                                   bottom = "auto",
                                   width = 200),
              
              #-----PANEL 3-----
              
              shinyjs::inlineCSS("#u-panel-3.ap { padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 0px; background-color: #cccccc; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px;}"),
              
              shiny::absolutePanel(id = "u-panel-3", style = "position: absolute;",
                                   class = "ap",
                                   fixed = TRUE,
                                   draggable = FALSE,
                                   top = 180,
                                   left = 263,
                                   right = "auto",
                                   bottom = "auto",
                                   width = 429,
                                   height = 178),
              
              #-----PANEL 4-----
              
              shinyjs::inlineCSS("#u-panel-4.ap { padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 30px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px; background-color: #cccccc; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px;}"),
              
              shiny::absolutePanel(id = "u-panel-4", style = "position: absolute;",
                                   class = "ap",
                                   fixed = TRUE,
                                   draggable = FALSE,
                                   top = 180,
                                   left = 700,
                                   right = "auto",
                                   bottom = "auto",
                                   width = 429,
                                   height = 178),
              
              #-----PANEL 5-----
              
              shinyjs::inlineCSS("#u-panel-5.ap { padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 30px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px; background-color: #cccccc; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px;}"),
              
              shiny::absolutePanel(id = "u-panel-5", style = "position: absolute;",
                                   class = "ap",
                                   fixed = TRUE,
                                   draggable = FALSE,
                                   top = 366,
                                   left = 55,
                                   right = "auto",
                                   bottom = "auto",
                                   width = 1074,
                                   height = 220),
              
              #-----PANEL 6-----
              
              shinyjs::inlineCSS("#u-panel-6.ap { padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 0px; background-color: #8ebfdb; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px;}"),
              
              shiny::absolutePanel(id = "u-panel-6", style = "position: absolute;",
                                   class = "ap",
                                   fixed = TRUE,
                                   draggable = FALSE,
                                   top = 594,
                                   bottom = "auto",
                                   left = 55,
                                   right = "auto",
                                   height = 177,
                                   width = 425),
              
              #-----PANEL 7-----
              
              shinyjs::inlineCSS("#u-panel-7.ap { padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 0px; background-color: #f4ac90; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px;}"),
              
              shiny::absolutePanel(id = "u-panel-7", style = "position: absolute;",
                                   class = "ap",
                                   fixed = TRUE,
                                   draggable = FALSE,
                                   top = 594,
                                   left = 489,
                                   right = "auto",
                                   bottom = "auto",
                                   height = 177,
                                   width = 640),
              
              #-----MAP PANEL-----
              
              shiny::absolutePanel(id = "u-map-panel", style = "position: absolute;",
                                   class = "ap",
                                   fixed = TRUE,
                                   draggable = FALSE,
                                   top = 60,
                                   left = 1138,
                                   right = "auto",
                                   bottom = "auto",
                                   height = 526,
                                   width = 552,
                                   
                                   #-----RENDER MAP-----
                                   
                                   shinyjs::inlineCSS("#my-map { border-style: solid; border-color: black; margin: 0px; border-width: 1px;}"),
                                   
                                   leaflet::leafletOutput("my-map", width="100%", height="100%")
                                   
              )
              
  ) # ** End test tab ** #

) # ** End UI function ** #


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #-----BASE MAP UI OUTPUT-----

  output$`my-map` <- leaflet::renderLeaflet({
    # Establish interactive map
    interactiveMap <- leaflet::leaflet(options=leaflet::leafletOptions(minZoom = 4, zoomControl = TRUE, dragging = TRUE)) %>%
      leaflet::addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") 
    # Return result
    return(interactiveMap)
  })

} # ** End server function ** #


shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I tested it again as-is and it is working well if the window is too small to fit all the content. Make sure you have the last Shiny version installed. You can look at the link I put on the answer to see it working.

Comment: You are correct! Your solution works perfectly. My apologies for the misunderstanding; I have deleted my original reply. I truly appreciate the assistance!